# How to create a tooltip on rows? Using Jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you a simple tooltip that displays a image and text when you hover over a row?
There are many rows and each row should have it owns unique image and text.

My table:

```
    <div id="tabel">
    <table id="tabel1" border="0" bordercolor="#000000" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr id="toptr">
          <td>Navn</td>
          <td>Bedommelse</td>
          <td>Vaerdi</td>
          <td>Tid</td>
          <td>Udtraekkes</td>
          <td>Type</td>
       </tr>
       <% end %>
    <% @konkurrancer.each do |vind| %>
       <tr onclick="window.open('<%= vind.tracking %>')" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onmouseover="this.style.background='#99ff33';this.style.cursor='pointer'">
          <img src="#" style="display:none"><img><p style="display:none">HOVER TEKST</p>
          <td><%= vind.navn %></td>
          <td>4 ud af 5</td>
          <td><%= number_to_currency(vind.vaerdi, :unit => "DKK", :separator => ".", :delimiter => ".", :format => "%n %u", :precision => 0) %></td>
          <td>2 min</td>
          <td>Nyhedsbrev</td>
          <td><%= vind.udtraekkes.strftime("%d %B") %></td>
       </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chin/2y4s4/). Just made a quick mashup with same example using the same code on the site.

Comment: Very nice were do I but the text ? :)

Comment: What if the img is javascript (flash) like <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dk.orvillemedia.com/ads/explicit/?aid=2190&pid=2922&zid=1" charset="utf-8"></script> ?

Comment: Adding text is not that difficult see the update version with text http://jsfiddle.net/chin/2y4s4/7/ . Can you please provide the code snippet for what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$('tr').hover(function()
{
  $(this).css('background-image', "url('foo.png')");
}, function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
});
```

You'd have to add some more code to make it not repeat and align it.

As for the text, you could cheat and make it an image, but that's a bit hacky. I'd actually make a hidden `div` with absolute positioning and make it appear whenever you hover.

Comment: There are alot of rows and it each should have its own image and tekst on hover

Comment: Can you show a exmaple like tooltip example 3 just with rows instead of a link? http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery

Comment: How will you determine the text and image? I'd just make a hidden `div` element for each row with all your stuff and then hide/show it when the row is hovered.

Comment: Can you show an example with an div inside a row ? :) like <tr><div style="display:none"><img src="#" /><p>HOVER TEKST</p></div><td></td><td></td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

Are you after tooltips, perhaps? Using jQuery, [here is a sample of some tooltips](http://visionwidget.com/inspiration/web/495-jquery-tooltip-plugins.html) you could use to display text and images (you'd create them in a `div` and then use CSS to show it).

Comment: Exactly just rows instead of links.